# Unable to refocus UITextField after storing pointer and resigning first responder

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield, first-responder

I am working with a grouped `UITableView` each containing a subclassed `UITextField` as its content view.  The subclassed `UITextField` only contains an additional property `indexPath` to store its position within the table.

The issue I face is that I want to record which text field is the current responder so I added a `UITextField` property to my view controller. I implemented the `textFieldDidBeginEditing` delegate method and when the method is called the `textField` pointer argument is stored as the first responder property of my view controller.

When in use the field is initially focusable, however if I end editing by pushing `Return` on the keyboard, the keyboard disappears and I am no longer able to bring the focus back to the original text field or any of the other text fields in the table.

If I remove the line `self.firstResponder = (LKCTableViewTextField *)textField;` from the `textFieldDidBeginEditing` delegate method all works as expected but I do not have the pointer to the text field set as first responder.

Has anyone had this issue or know of what's going on?

Thanks,

Eric

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sorry not understood correctly, to see if it serves you to save a reference to textfield.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    activeField = textField;
}
```

Comment: The real issue is that I need to get the pointer to the current text field not hide the keyboard.  The keyboard gets hidden with no issue.  If I do not include the code to hide the keyboard after editing has finished but still try to store the pointer to the text field that was editing, none of the text fields are focusable.

Comment: I should also note that I am using developing in iOS 7, if this makes a difference.